# Using Knitr engine in TeXshop but pdf plot labels with accented letters are incorrect

Tags: encoding, text-editor, knitr

I want to compile the following Rnw file  containing an R plot of the normal density function.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}    

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(dev = "pdf", comment = NA, fig.align='center', cache=FALSE, message=FALSE, background='white')
options(replace.assign=TRUE, width=85)
knit_hooks$set(fig=function(before, options, envir){if (before) par(mar=c(4,4,.1,.1),cex.lab=.95,cex.axis=.9,mgp=c(2,.7,0),tcl=-.3)})
@
<<prepare-data, include=FALSE>>=
@
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


\begin{document}
This is a plot with an italian caption ``Densità'' that means ``Density''. 
<<norm, echo = FALSE, fig.width=4, fig.height=3.5>>=
curve(dnorm(x), -4, 4, xlab = 'z', ylab = 'Densità')
 @
\end{document}
```

The file has UTF-8 encoding.

Then I compile the file with R and knitr with

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit2pdf('~/Desktop/label.Rnw')"
```

I get the correct plot with a label "Densità" (in italian means density, last letter is accented).

I'm using MacOSX 10.10 Yosemite and my R locale is

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

The problem comes using TeXShop. I use the knitr.engine suggested here: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/
and compile the file label.Rnw.

Now a get a wrong label in the plot, i.e., "Density" becomes "Densit..". 
However I get correct accented letters in the text.

Anybody knows why?